# Discord.py check second part of command

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I check the value of the second part of a command? Lets say my command is called `checkvalue` then how can I check the last part given. For example `!checkvalue example` then how can I fetch the example part?

Comment: Consider reading the discord.py Documentation:

Comment: Here, first example, this is for passing parameters in your command, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def checkvalue(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, discord commands can be defined like this

```
@command()
async def checkvalue(self, ctx: Context, parameter_1: str):
    print("first parameter is :", parameter_1)
```

This will function will be called when you type `!checkvalue example` (assuming that those 3 lines of code are not the only code of your bot) and you will see as output on the terminal first parameter is : example

Please note that if you change `parameter_1: str` to `parameter_1: Member`, your bot will assume the second parameter is a mentionned user, and you will be able to use all the method of [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) of that parameter easily